# I need to define a custom work week in MS access

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a custom function on a form to define a week Number.

I have created a table that defines the week number.

Example WeekNo, StartDay, End Day
example: WeekNo 1 StartDay = 3/29/2020, End Day 4/4/2020

I have a Date box on my form if I enter a date of 3/29/2020
I would like 1 to be populated in my week number box.

On my form in the row source I have designed a Dlookup query

=DLookup("[WeekNumber]", "tblWeekNumber", "[Startdate] >= " & frmSearchNew.dt_Date & "") & [EndDate] <= frmSearchNew.dtDate

When I change to from view I get the error the record source specified on this form does not exist.
The table tblWeekNumber has the fields  ID, WeekNo, StartDay and EndDay.

Where am I going wrong? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the DLookup that you have put together.

1. Firstly, the field that you are looking for and the fields that you are using as criteria do not appear to match those in the table - WeekNumber/WeekNo, StartDate/StartDay, EndDate/EndDay;
2. Next, the logic for the lookup is wrong. You are trying to find a the week number that has a start date that is greater than the entered date, and an end date that is less than the entered date. What you should be looking for is a start date **before** the entered date, and an end date **after** the entered date.
3. Finally, dates are a bit funny in Access. You need to wrap them in '#' so that Access knows they are dates, and you should also take care to disambiguate them - 03/04/2020 could be either 3rd April or 4th March depending on you nationality.

Putting it all together, the final control source should look like:

```
=DLookUp("WeekNo","tblWeekNumber","StartDay<=#" & Format([dt_Date],"dd-mmm-yyyy") & "# AND EndDay>=#" & Format([dt_Date],"dd-mmm-yy") & "#")
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank for your clarifications. I am still getting an error that record source on this form does not exist. I am putting the formula in the record source of the form I am using. The form properties are pointing to another table. I tried to add the name of the form(frmSearchNew!)  to the dt_Date but I still get the same error.

Comment: You should be setting the DLookup to the controlsource of a TextBox, not the form.

Comment: I moved the formula to the After Update event, the error went away but now I get no information in the WeekNumber box after I type in the Date in the dt_Date box

Comment: OK, I see the issue I had the box set to a list box. Once I changed it to a text box everything worked. Sorry, it has been a couple of years since I looked at Access, I am rusty. Thanks for your help !!